# Boxing System.RuntimeArgumentHandle

Tags: .net, cil

I am working on an interpreter for MSIL code. When it comes to boxing, there are some known restrictions, for example, it's impossible to box byref-like structs.

Regarding System.RuntimeArgumentHandle, I noticed that for .NET Framework (unlike .NET Core), System.RuntimeArgumentHandle is just a struct, so it seems that boxing is allowed. However, the following program is invalid:

```
locals init (valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeArgumentHandle V_0)

ldloca.s   V_0
initobj    [mscorlib]System.RuntimeArgumentHandle

ldloc V_0
box [mscorlib]System.RuntimeArgumentHandle
pop
```

Furthermore, if I use an old Visual Studio 2008 and try to compile the following code, it fails with the error "Cannot convert type 'System.RuntimeArgumentHandle' to 'object'":

```
var o = (object)new RuntimeArgumentHandle();
```

Why is it not allowed to box RuntimeArgumentHandle, and how does the compiler understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boxing `System.RuntimeArgumentHandle` is a special case in the spec. ECMA-335, 5th edition, 8.2.1.1, emphasis added:

> The value types **System.RuntimeArgumentHandle** and System.ArgIterator (see Partition IV and CIL
> instruction arglist in Partition III), contain pointers into the VES stack. They can be used for local variable
> and parameter signatures. The use of these types for fields, method return types, the element type of an array, or
> in **boxing** is **not verifiable** (§8.8). These two types are referred to as byref-like types.

Comment: The same goes for `System.TypedReference` too. These were always ref-like (or stricter), even when the rules weren't codified into the language yet.